# Currently, if we need to do reduce or forEach on iterable or iterator, would we just have to polyfill it?

Tags: ecmascript-6, iterator, iterable

First of all, does it'd make sense to have some array methods such as `reduce` or `forEach` also for iterables and iterators?  Is it true that to use them and not wanting to blow up an array of a huge size, we just have to polyfill them for now?

Comment: You can have an infinite iterable - a `forEach` will then take forever to execute. Does it make sense to *always* have an iteration method?

Comment: isn't it true that if you do `[...obj]`, then it can already be an infinite loop? So if we can do `[...obj]`, why not `obj.reduce()`?

Comment: `[..obj]` is similar to `Array.from()`.  Both have the inefficiency of constructing an actual real array object that has is a separate data structure in memory. For large collections, this is very inefficient versus just iterating the native collection.  If you know that the inefficiency is fine for your application, you can always just do that  and then use the array methods. But, that's different than saying that the language should implicitly do that for you.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

What you propose is being worked on.  There is a [proposal at stage 2 of the TC39 process](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) for adding a whole bunch of helper methods to the iterator prototype (so they'd be usable by collections) and the proposal includes the two you mention `.forEach()` and `.reduce()` along with a dozen others.

I don't yet fully understand how this is supposed to work because the spec talks about iterator helpers, but then shows using `.reduce()` on an actual `Set` instance directly, just like you would use it on an array.  So, maybe the helpers are used by each class to implement their own method of that name.  Since you typically want to reduce a collection, not reduce an iterator, that would make some sense.  The iterator is just a tool used in the reduction of the collection, not the collection itself.

They [redefine the `.reduce()` callback](https://tc39.es/proposal-iterator-helpers/#sec-iteratorprototype-reduce) to only pass the accumulator and value (no index, no object).  FYI, I discovered this by looking at the very end of https://node.green/.  So, it is being worked on and since there is a proposed standard, you could polyfill it and you can find sample implementations for tons of proposed new iterator methods [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/tree/master/packages/core-js/modules).

Here's a polyfill for the proposed `Set.prototype.reduce()` and `Map.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
(function() {
if (!Set.prototype.reduce) {
    Object.defineProperty(Set.prototype, "reduce", {value: reduce});
}
if (!Map.prototype.reduce) {
    Object.defineProperty(Map.prototype, "reduce", {value: reduce});
}

function reduce(fn, initialValue) {
    if (typeof fn !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError("2nd argument to reduce must be function");
    }
    let noInitial = arguments.length < 2;
    let accumulator = initialValue;
    for (let [key, value] of this.entries()) {
        // if no initial value, get it from the first value
        if (noInitial) {
            accumulator = value;
            noInitial = false;
        } else {
            accumulator = fn(accumulator, key, value);
        }
    }
    // if there was nothing to iterate and initialValue was not passed
    // spec says this should be a TypeError
    if (noInitial) {
        throw new TypeError("iterable was empty and initalValue not passed")
    }
    return accumulator;
}

})();    

// demo code

let s = new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

let sum = s.reduce((total, val) => {
return total += val;
}, 0);

console.log(`Set Total = ${sum}`);


let m = new Map([['one',1],['two',2],['three',3],['four',4]]);

let sum2 = m.reduce((total, key, val) => {
return total += val;
}, 0);

console.log(`Map Total = ${sum2}`);
```

I have not quite figured out how a `.reduce()` method on a base `Iterator` class automatically makes it so that `set.reduce()` or `map.reduce()` will "just work".  I'm not sure it does.  I'm thinking that each class still has to wire up it's own `.reduce()` method, but it can use the helper implementation on the Iterator object to do so.  Perhaps that's why they are called "helpers".  They're just common functions that can be used to wire up your own top level method.

They can probably still be accessed on an iterator directly, but that doesn't seem how you would typically use them.

---

**Original answer...**

You do not really need `forEach()` because you can just use `for/of` on any iterable. So, if you really wanted `forEach()`, you would have to implement it yourself.  I wouldn't call it a polyfill because there is no standard you're trying to fill-in for.  As such, it would be better to make it a stand-alone function, not pollute the prototype in a non-standard way.

There are certainly some arguments for having a `reduce()` like function that works with an iterable if you're just trying to iterate and collect some single value from the iteration.  Again, since there is no standard implementation for all iterables, you'd have to implement your own function that works with any iterable.

One problem with implementing `reduce()` for any arbitrary iterable is that `Array.prototype.reduce()` passes an `index` to the callback.  This somewhat assumes that there is access by that `index` like an array has.  But, some collections that have are an iterable do not have access by index.  You could still create an index during the iteration and pass it to the callback as just a counter, but it could not necessarily be used the way the index is used when doing `someArray.reduce()`.

Here's an implementation of `reduce()` that works on any iterable.  For reference here's [the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) for `Array.prototype.reduce()` which works off indexed access, not off an iterable which is why it can't be used directly on any iterable, but can be used on any Array-like object.

```js
let s = new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

function reduce(iterable, fn, initialValue) {
    if (typeof fn !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError("2nd argument to reduce must be function");
    }
    let initialValuePresent = arguments.length >= 3;
    let accumulator = initialValue;
    let cntr= 0;
    for (let item of iterable) {
        // if no initial value, get it from the first value
        if (cntr === 0 && !initialValuePresent) {
            accumulator = item;
        } else {
            accumulator = fn(accumulator, item, cntr, iterable);
        }
        ++cntr;
    }
    // if there was nothing to iterate and initialValue was not passed
    // spec says this should be a TypeError
    if (cntr === 0 && !initialValuePresent) {
        throw new TypeError("iterable was empty and initalValue not passed")
    }
    return accumulator;
}

let sum = reduce(s, (total, item, cntr, obj) => {
    return total += item;
}, 0);

console.log(`Total = ${sum}`);
```

Comment: `for-of` won't give the index, like `forEach((a, i) => {}` but so I guess the third parameter should not be provided, because we might not want the whole array to begin with

Comment: initially, I thought `reduce` should not be that complicated for iterables -- how come it didn't go into the ES6 or even ES7 or ES8 and already came into V8 and Node

Comment: @nopole - It's always hard for us to answer "why" something didn't get done.  The only way to really know that is to have been in the discussion at the time among those deciding what features to spend time on or to find a record of the discussion and see why they decided what they decided.  The general move to iterables was a big internal change affecting lots of things.  From my own software experience, I can imagine wanting to bite off a manageable chunk of work, make it  work really well and then see what things people thought were the most important going forward.

Comment: @nopole - `.reduce()`, like `.forEach()` are programming conveniences that just save a little typing.  One can always accomplish your `.reduce()` goal with a regular `for` or `for/of` loop and just keep track of your own accumulator through the loop.  As such, no functionality in the language is blocked by not having it on any arbitrary iterable.  That alone makes it a lower priority than many things.  But, I don't honestly know why they chose not to implement it.  Perhaps the `index` that it provides just associates it too much with an array-like object that an iterable does not have to be.

Comment: the index may be one thing... can the index make sense but I guess it can if it is converted to an array. The `reduce` is quite useful such as `iter.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)` and it is done

Comment: @nopole - For a non-array-like iterable, the `index` would really just be a counter, not really an index as you couldn't use it to access anything in the object.  That's what it is in the `reduce()` implementation in my answer.

Comment: @nopole - FYI, ffrom reddit: [Why don't iterators support map, reduce, filter, etc?](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/4gatmp/why_dont_iterators_support_map_reduce_filter_etc/).  And, there's a library for this: [JavaScript library providing higher order functions (such as map, filter, and reduce) for ECMAScript 6 iterators](https://fitzgen.github.io/wu.js/).

Comment: @nopole - FYI, that above referenced library (in the previous comment) doesn't pass the `index` or the `object` to the `reduce()` callback.  It only passes the first 2 of the 4 arguments.  So, they just punted on the `index` entirely.

Comment: @nopole - Here's another implementation that just skips the `index` and `object` arguments to the callback: [Implementing reduce for iterables](https://medium.com/winnintech/implementing-reduce-in-javascript-part-1-7ea8711e194).  This implementation also requires that the initialValue for the accumulator be passed unlike the standard Array implementation.

Comment: could it be polyfilled as `iterable.reduce()`? But maybe if no implementation has it, then it shouldn't be polyfilled. Come to think about it, I wonder why `iterator.reduce()` should not work, as `[...iterator]` shouldn't either (only iterable should work). On the other hand, if `iter = generatorFn()`, then `[...iter]` actually works because iter is both an iterable and iterator.

Comment: @nopole - You could add your new feature to any specific iterable, but iterables don't necessarily have a common parent class that you can add your implementation in one place so you'd have to add it to every iterable that you want to use it on, including all sorts of custom iterables.  That's why I don't think `iterable.reduce()` makes a lot of sense.  I think a function `reduce(iterable, fn)` makes more sense because then one implementation can be used for all iterables.

Comment: @nopole - Please don't use the phrase "polyfill" that way. A polyfill is a means of adding a known standard implementation and specification to an older version of code that doesn't yet have it. There is no standard implementation for `reduce()` on an iterator. What you are discussing is not a polyfill. It's a new non-standard feature you want to add to some iterators. I personally wouldn't do it that way as that general practice tends to run afoul of future changes and conflicts with other libraries, etc... An actual polyfill is safe because it's a known, standard implementation.

Comment: @nopole - As we've already discussed, you can always do `Array.from(iterable).reduce()` or `[...iterable].reduce()` with the drawback of making a temporary array and iterating the data twice.

Comment: yes, and I guess in JS it might not be too often that you would actually iterate from 1 to a million. But maybe as server code or if people start writing scripts using JS on the computer to run, then range(1, 1000000) will not be too efficient if needing to convert to an array first

Comment: With support for [this-binding syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) (currently a proposal) you could have a generic `reduce` method and then execute it against an iterable like so `iterable::reduce(reducer)`

Comment: @VLAZ - Interesting proposal.  I'm not familiar with the this-binding benefits as they relate to this issue.  How is that better than `reduce(iterable, ...)`?

Comment: @jfriend00 I guess it's pretty much the same, just instead of having `reduce(target, reducer)` you'd have `reduce(reducer)` and use `this` instead of `target`. So, the operation will be pretty much the same - it's just a different way of thinking about and implementing the functionality. It allows you to have free methods you dynamically "add" (or "execute against") an instance, so you could have a `reduce` method for iterables. A `reduce` pure function also works. Don't think either has any significant benefits or drawbacks. It depends on what one finds more readable.

Comment: @nopole - FYI, I just discovered that `Set.prototype.reduce()` and `Map.prototype.reduce()` (along with many other collection methods) are [proposed](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-collection-methods).  I realize this is not a generic iterator implementation.  You can see in their proposal that they are NOT passing an index to the callback.  For Map, they are passing value and key.  For Set, they are just passing two copies of the value (probably to stick with a similar callback format).  Internal to the implementation, it appears they using an iterator on `.entries()` (which makes sense).

Comment: @nopole - Oh, and here's [proposed iterator helpers](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-iterator-helpers) which includes `reduce()`.  These are in Stage 2 of the TC39 process.  They [redefine the callback](https://tc39.es/proposal-iterator-helpers/#sec-iteratorprototype-reduce) to only pass the accumulator and value.  FYI, I discovered this by looking at the very end of https://node.green/.  So, it  is being worked on.  I've modified the start of my answer to incorporate this.

Comment: @VLAZ - See the previous comment (or the edited beginning of my answer).  There is a proposal to add methods like `.reduce()` directly to the iterator prototype.

Comment: @nopole - Did this answer your question?  You've asked quite a few questions in the last month (30 questions since Dec. 27), several of which I've put a lot of effort into answers for.  Most of your questions do not have an accepted answer (only 4 accepted answers out of those 30).  Is there really not an answer worthy of accepting to those other 26 questions?  Or are you just not wrapping up questions by selecting the best answer?  With 116k of reputation, I presume you know how the process of accepting an answer is supposed to work.